# Proposing a new tag opens a pop up modal which is hidden

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

When I click on the 'propose a new tag' button in Documentation, the modal or search tag window is hidden and there is no scroll bar to reach the bottom.

[image: screen shot of occluded modal]

To avoid this, I have to scroll up and when there is enough space for the modal to be accommodated, I click 'propose a new tag' button.

[image: screen shot after scrolling]

And now searching for a tag is fine.

Don't know to say it a bug, but it is definitely not user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next build.